# Change CakePHP default redirect from HTTP to HTTPS?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have project which is here `http://www.example.com`. I can simply login with this link but can't login `https://www.example.com`. How to change the CakePHP default redirection.

The site is working properly when I use http but not working with https.

Comment: not working in what way? (-1 for a "it's broken" question with no information)

Comment: What's a "default redirection"? Is your site already configured to work under HTTPS?

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario 1  thx! actually have no idea about http and https detail. I just can login with https... why?

Comment: You can or you cannot login with HTTPS? If you cannot, what exactly prevents you from doing it? If you don't know if *your* site works with HTTPS, how can *we* know?

Comment: Assuming `https://www.example.com` exists and is accessible, CakePHP does not change host or protocol by default - whatever the problem is it's a misunderstanding, application config or application code (none of which is possible to solve from the info in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SecurityComponent::requireSecure` ([See](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#restrict-actions-to-ssl)) to force SSL for all actions, but as said before SSL should be enabled / supported on/by your webserver. It seems to me that this is not really a CakePHP problem.